# I removed a symbolic link, and Ubuntu became unusable

Tags: sudo, symbolic-link

I removed the symbolic link for '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so' in the directory '/usr/lib64'.  Suddenly most everything stopped working.  I cannot even issue simple Linux commands like 'pwd', 'ls', 'sudo'.  Since 'sudo' disappeared, I cannot even restore the symbolic link I removed.

I am DIW.  Please help if you know what I should do to recover.

For the record, I am running Ubuntu Mate 20.04 LTS on a desktop machine.

Comment: @ArturMeinild Please write that as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

You removed a component of `libc6`, which is used by nearly everything. You should probably boot a live USB, mount your harddisk and fix the error using the live boot. Please note that I didn't test this.

Please use the [official Ubuntu guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) to boot a Live USB with Ubuntu.

Find out what your harddisk device name is: (I assume it's the old root partition - find the partion that matches the size)

```
lsblk
```

When the live system is running, mount your harddisk: (I assume your harddisk is /dev/sda2)

```
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/disk
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt/disk
```

Create the missing symlink:

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so /mnt/disk/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Now shut down the system, remove the USB, and start Ubuntu as normal. Functionality should be restored.

Comment: Yes it worked, thank you Arthur Meinild.  While fixing it, I also learned something new.  I would have added '/mnt/disk/' in front of '/lib/...' in the 'ln -s' command.  That would have been wrong.  Your prescription was dead on.

Comment: That's good to know. Yes the link will initially link to the `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.31.so` of the "live" system. But since the link is static, when you reboot to your normal system, now it will link there instead. Please do me a favor and accept my answer, since it worked for you. Cheers! 